# Wordpress HTML form does not redirect properly after submit

Tags: php, wordpress

So I have a form submission that works really well not on a wordpress. However, once I integrate it to wordpress. The redirect that shows the results(sends info) says that the page cannot be found, even if when I reload it the page suddenly show up. Here is an example of the error that I get

[Error. Page redirects properly after reload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xR3BB.png)

```
    <form action="http://localhost/wordpress/results/" method="post">
    <center>
        <?php
        $make_vars = get_make();
        echo '<select class="selectpicker" id="s1" name="make" onchange="AjaxFunction();listener();">
        <option>Select One</option>';
        foreach ($make_vars as $key){
            echo '<option value='.$key.'>'.$key.'</option>';
        } 
        ?>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <?php
        echo '<select class="selectpicker" name="model" id="s2" onchange="AjaxFunction2();listener();" >
        <option>Select One</option>';

        ?>
    </select>
    <br>e
    <br>
    <?php
        echo '<select class="selectpicker" name="year" id="s3" onchange="listener();" >
        <option>Select One</option>';

        ?>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input class="btn btn-success" id="Button" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </center>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that that URL to the results page is correct? Just try a different URL / file in the action element to see if a different page loads up. Also, clear your browsers cache every so often.

Comment: Yes because once I reload the page it works. However all the data is lost